# jQuery / CSS - detect overflow without going through all the elements

Tags: jquery, css, overflow

I would like to know if there is a way to detect which td's of a table are overflown without going through all of them.

So far, if I want to target the overflown td's I have to do this:

```
$('.table_x td').each(function(){
    //Check size of each td's text compared to the container by creating a clone
    //if(clone_container>actual_container){console.log('overflow')}
});
```

What I would like to do is exactly that but only for the td's that are overflown:

In that kind of way:

```
$('.table_x td: (is_overflown')).each{//console.log('overflow')}
```

Is it possible?

**Question has been edited to focus on what's needed.**

Comment: I'm assuming the reason you are seeing "lag" is because your resize event listener is not throttled.  You should consider adding a throttle or debounce to your resize event listener to solve this issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If throttling/debouncing is about limiting the rate of the process while resizing, as mentioned in the question, it's an issue. I have to know if there is an overflow the exact moment there is one. It's one of the question's requirements.

Comment: But you do not need to know for **every** resize event, given that there is a resize event fired for pretty much every pixel change.  As far as the user is concerned, it's typically enough to only process a resize event once per duration, such as something low like 200-300 milliseconds.  Processing a single resize event once per that duration drastically reduces the amount of work you are forcing javascript to do, and improves the user experience.

Comment: It will be easier to help with optimisations if you actually give the code for `//dostuff. Also tell why you need to check the overflow? You have already been given an advice that is best practice for the things you are trying to do with the information provided.

Comment: It is not about the user. It is about knowing exactly at which size in px the overflow happened when it happens. So when the overflow happens, I detect the td size. With throttling or debouncing it will only give me the size when the check has been made, not when the overflow happened. Right?

Comment: It's always about the user.  I can't begin to express how that statement is troubling.

Comment: With all due respect, not in the way you put it. When I want to get some info in a variable to store it somewhere, it's not about the user here. if It was about the user experience, I would limit the number of process to what he can perceive. But when I want to store at what size something happened exactly, it's not about the user perception, it's about the precise size I need to store. Throttling would approximate the size. I need to know that size up to the pixel. Granted, if you see the lag as a user experience, then it is. But it won't solve my problem as I need to know the exact size.

Comment: Is your logic ignoring resize events once it determines the dimension at which the overflow happens?  Lets say the box is being resized from 200 to 100, and overflow starts at anything under 150.  Once you determine that the overflow happens at 150, are you ignoring the events that are greater than 150?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. Yes, BUT it has to detect this for each and every other td that has been overflown anyway so the check will have to occur at each resize (unless ALL of the td's have been overflown). I edited my original question because I think it gave the impression that it was about the "dostuff" and lag while it never was. What I just want to know is if I need to check every td size to detect its overflow or if there is a built-in way to automatically detect those which are overflown when they are. The edited question is now clearer.